# How to make UILabel NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle attributedString center for Capital Letters

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have the following method that works fine for labels with capitalized and lower case letters.

```
  func strikeThroughLabel(label: UILabel) {
      let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: label.text!, attributes: [NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue])
      label.attributedText = attributedString
  }
```

The problem is that the strikethrough line is not vertically centered for labels containing all capitalized letters.

What is the easiest way to solve this rather inconvenient problem?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your issue, at least not in a Storyboard ([image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ylG1z.png)).  Am I missing something?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/3dYK3C9.png It is also occurring in your example, it is not vertically centered. Put another label like "Hello World" next to it with a strikethrough and it becomes more obvious.

Comment: Oh the line itself is not centered, I see what you're saying.

Comment: Not a complete solution, but what about using an undocumented `NSUnderlineStyle` value for the `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName`, such as integers 4 through 7 (instead of `NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle`)?  They aren't perfect, but might bring you closer to your request.

Comment: Did any of those help?  I think `4` is closest to what you want, even though it is rather large.

Comment: I do need the height of the line to be identical. For my uilabel it is still not quite centered verically with any of those rawValues.

Comment: try to capture image and upload it

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not a very good solution. I must say this is quite opposite what you need.

Instead of adjusting the line itself, I would recommend using `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName`, this will adjust the text baseline a bit up/down as you need.

This should make the line appear vertically in center with respect to `text` of the `UILabel`.

Hope it is acceptable to your requirements.